# Problem in connection code

Tags: android, wifi

this is my class to connect and send commands to server i try separate connect code in method
but when i test the (SocketConnect) method i found it doesn't work.
my code

```
public class ConnAndSend {

     static Socket socket = null;


        static void SendCommand(String cmnd)  {

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

        try {   

             dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
             dataOutputStream.writeUTF(cmnd);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
                 }  
                finally{

                      if (dataOutputStream != null){
                       try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                       }}

                      };

        }
        // method to connect to server
        static void SocketConnect(String SrvrIP,int SrvrPrt) {
         //      Socket socket = null;
             try {   

                 socket = new Socket(SrvrIP, SrvrPrt);   

                 } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

             finally{

               if (socket != null){
               try {
                socket.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
               }}

        }
```

Comment: What's the problem? what is the error you get?

Comment: when i call SocketConnect then connection to server does not happen and when call SendCommand i get error  " the app... has stoped unexpectedly please try again

Comment: if i put socket = new Socket(SrvrIP, SrvrPrt) in SendCommand method then it works well.. but i want to sperate it.

Comment: Wait a minute. When do you call SocketConnect?

Answer (score 1):

- **Remove** the ***static*** modifier!!

  Remove all the occurances of the word ***static***

---

In your code:

```
    socket = new Socket(SrvrIP, SrvrPrt);   
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
        if (socket != null){
            try {
            socket.close();
```

you are closing the socket in `finally` (why?) this is wrong also!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your manifest file has the correct permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing the socket before you even get a chance to use it or you are'nt calling SocketConnect before . Do you see how you you make the socket, then you close it?

```
    socket = new Socket(SrvrIP, SrvrPrt);   
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    finally{
        if (socket != null){
            try {
            socket.close();
```

You need to make the socket, use it to connect in your SendCommand, then close it. I'm not quite sure why you need to keep the two separate, but I believe that is your problem, you are calling close before you use the socket to connect or you simply aren't making the socket and `SendCommand` is using "null" to connect.

Comment: I need to separate it to make each one in button. and i don't understand the last point "using "null" to connect".

Comment: Honestly and I don't mean this in a bad way, just that it seems that you are a beginner (and from reading your other questions), I think you need to do a little more research into java and android. From the title and what each method looks like it does `SocketConnect` needs to be called first as it it making the connection to the server and `SendCommand` is where you actually send data or receive data from the server. You might want to make a constructor that sets the SrvrIP and the SrvrPrt to get you started.

Comment: yes I'm a beginner and I need to correct my code above If it is possible..thank you